# Integration for Advanced Learners

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, complex-integration

I am a Young leaner of Mathematics in the university and I found this problem a bit challenging et me.

Please can someone help me integrate

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^{-2}} dx$$
Thanks.

Comment: @Sobi this is actually quite challenging for a beginner...

Comment: I tried to use integration by part. But it never finishes. Then when I applied the limits, it turns to pi

Comment: @JordanFondja this integral doesn't converge actually. If you plot the integrand out, you will notice that $e^{-x^{-2}}\to1$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ so the area under the graph till infinity can't be found.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat I am well aware of that. Just wanted to see how he thinks.

Comment: @Sobi actually without putting the limits, the integration never finishes. Is there another method apart from bypart To solve it?

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat ok. Now i have change the question. From -x To x. Can this converge?

Comment: By the way, do you mean $e^{-x^2}$ for the integrand though? If yes, check this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat No. It is x To the power -2

Answer (score 2):

You probably want $-x^2$, and not $-x^{-2}$, because in the latter case the integral does not converge.

There is no known way to calculate this integral directly. The indirect method involves moving one dimension upwards, and looking at the double integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy$$

Using some non-trivial theory, it is possible to show that this integral is precisely the square of the integral you are looking for, on one hand, and on the other hand, using some non-trivial theory of coordinate-transformations, it is possible to calculate this double integral directly, by showing that it is equal to the integral
$$2\pi\int_0^{\infty}r{e^{-r^2}}\,dr$$
which can actually be easily computed, as the integrand is the derivative of $-e^{-r^2}/2$.

But you need to know a few things in order to get there. Don't waste time on trying to compute it directly. It is probably impossible.

Comment: I'm loss. As you said i've to know few things before I reach there.

Comment: @JordanFondja yeah it's really a very difficult integral to handle. You can google 'Gaussian integrals'.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Ok. Thanks

Comment: From what author said, it's $e^{x^{-2}}$, not $e^{-x^2}$...